# Scala: understanding how to make my method return the proper return type of Array

Tags: scala

I have written the following Scala code:

```
class MyTestApi {
     private def toCPArray(inputStr: String): Array[Int] = {
      val len = inputStr.length
    //invoke ofDim of Scala.Array
    val cpArray = Array.ofDim[Int](inputStr.codePointCount(0, len))
    var i = 0
    var j = 0
    while (i < len) {
      cpArray(j += 1) = inputStr.codePointAt(i)
      i = inputStr.offsetByCodePoints(i, 1)
    }
    cpArray
  }           

}
```

---

This is what I want to accomplish:

I would create an instance of class `MyTestApi` and then invoke the method `toCPArray` and pass to it a parameter of type `String`. I would then like this method to return me an `Array[Int].

However as it stands now, the Scala IDE is complaining about this line:

```
**cpArray(j += 1) = inputStr.codePointAt(i)**
```

> type mismatch; Found: Unit required: Int

Two things I would like to accomplish are:

1. How would I fix this method? (or is it a function)
   My hope is, after I understand what it takes to fix this method (or function) I will be able to return the appropriate type. Also, I should be in better position to understand the difference between a method and a function.

So far my research on stackoverflow and Martin Odersky's book seems to suggests to me that what I wrote is a method because it is invokded on an instance of the underlying class. Is my understanding right on that?

2. After it is fixed, how can i rewrite it in a more Scalaesque way, by getting rid of the var. The code looks more C or java like right now and is a little long in my opinion, after all that I have studied about Scala so far.

Thanks for any help in refactoring the above code to accomplish my learning objectives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `cpArray.update` with an assignment statement which evaluates to `Unit` when it expects an `Integer`. You need to call it with an `Integer`:

```
j += 1
cpArray(j) = inputStr.codePointAt(i)
```

Comment: That worked. Okay, so it was the assignment statement.  Is there any (more functional) way to shorten the code?

Answer (score 2):

Many questions in one. I try to answer them all.

First of all as Jörg pointed out, moving the assignment makes the code work. Contrary to Java and C, Scala's assignment doesn't return the assigned value but `Unit`.

Now for making it idiomatic. Scala's `String` can be seem as `IndexedSeq[Char]`, meaning you can generally treat them as `IndexedSeqs`. So you doing do something like:

```
inputStr.map{ x => x.toInt }.toArray
```

This will return an Array[Int]. Notice it will only work for 16-bits `char` representations. Hopefully it will help in giving an idea of idiomatic Scala, even not being a perfect solution.

For the difference between methods and functions, it's simple: methods are generally `defs` in a class. Functions one the other hands are `Objects` in the JVM sense. For example, the above `map` could be defined like:

```
def map(f: Function1[Char, Int]):IndexedSeq[Int]
// or
def map(f: Char => Int):IndexedSeq[Int]
```

Both are the same, `=>` desugars to one of the `scala.FunctionN` (N from 0 to 22 inclusive).

And `x => x.toInt` is desugared in a similar way into a instance of `scala.Function1`. See it's [Scaladoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Function1).

So, functions are objects of type `scala.FunctionN`.

Note: to keep things simple I omitted a few details like `type parameters`, `val`s (which often compiles to JVM methods) and probably a few more details.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time and effort to answer. Sorry about asking so many questions all at once. I am reading your answer now. And learning quite a bit from it.

Comment: Functions are objects in the JVM sense. Great answer!